# Ionic 3 White screen in IPAD

Tags: ios, ipad, build, ionic3

I am developing an app using ionic 3. The app is working fine when I installed it in android and Iphone6. But the app is not working in  ipad.In ipad after the splashscreen the splashscreen is fading and a white blank screen is displaying forever. There is no error in the console while USB debugged.Please help me in sorting out the issue.

Comment: i'm having the same problem, do you already found the solution?